# IUPAC name of C₆(CH₃)₆²⁺

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds, carbocation

What is the correct IUPAC name (or least incorrect one, if the current rules can't precisely describe that) of the interesting species $\ce{[C6(CH3)6]^{2+}}$ (which is extensively discussed [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/68052/544)), containing exotic hexacoordinate [pyramidal carbocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidal_carbocation)<sup>*</sup> ?

The structure can be drawn as

[image: structure formula]

or

[image: structure formula 2]

My guess is **methyl(pentamethyl-η<sup>5</sup>-cyclopentadienyl)carbon(2+)**.

---

**) Some structures in the Wikipedia article have the two positive charges placed into the cyclopentadienyl (aromatic) ring, which I think is incorrect.*

Comment: Rather preferred (PIN) or one of various others (general etc.) then (in)correct.

Comment: This article on Wikipedia is based on stuff that was published 40 or more years ago :( There has to be 2+ formal charge on apical carbon, but not _real_ charge.

Comment: @Mithoron .. and the "least incorrect" variant request was for the case if the current rules are incapable of that.. my question rewording edit covers that as well, sort of. I think organic nomenclature cannot handle this, and inorganic nomenclature does not have PINs.

Answer (score 5):

From the [IUPAC Gold Boo](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/C/C00817.html)k:

> Carbocations may be named by adding the word 'cation' to the name of the corresponding radical. Such names do not imply structure (e.g. whether three-coordinated or five-coordinated carbon atoms are present).

So since this is the [dication of hexamethylbenzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexamethylbenzene#Dication), it would probably  least incorrectly be called hexamethylbenzene dication. At the very least, this seems to be how [a lot of people refer to it](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C44&q=%22hexamethylbenzene%20dication%22&btnG=) (or more verbosely, pentagonal-pyramidal hexamethylbenzene dication).